# How to remove default anchor tags added to text blocks in Oxygen Builder when publishing or previewing a page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am facing an issue with Oxygen Builder, a popular page builder for WordPress. When I add a text block to my page and apply styling and formatting within the Oxygen Builder editor, everything looks perfect. However, when I publish or preview the page, I notice that the text block is enclosed within  tags that are added automatically.

I would like to remove these default anchor tags that are added by Oxygen Builder when I publish or preview the page. I have tried various solutions, but none of them seem to work.

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

- I am using the latest version of Oxygen Builder.
- I have checked the settings and options within Oxygen Builder, but I
  couldn't find any specific option to disable or remove these default
  anchor tags.
- I have also checked the WordPress editor and settings, but couldn't
  find any relevant options there either.

I would appreciate any guidance or solution to help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!